# TFS restrict access

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops

We are using VS 2012 with TFS 2012.
We want to prevent some users to view  particular source files in a project,
We know how do this,Actually by right clicking on the files on the source control window and manage permissions in security tab.
The problem is that when we prevent a user to  view or change a file such as HomeController.cs
the user can't build the project and the vs IDE says that the file does not exist,

How we prevent access a file with the ability of  successful building project for the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prevent read / view permission then how can the compiler access the file in order to build it?  If the compiler can see the file then so can the user.

Are you sure that you want to prevent these users from even seeing the file, or do you just want to prevent them from changing the files?  If it's the latter then you can simply remove the permission to check-in.

Comment: You right,I want to prevent these users from even seeing the file,But if we do this then they can't build the project and develope other parts

Comment: I don't believe there's a way around that in TFS.  In fact, I don't think there's a way around it in .NET.  Even if you separated your code into pre-compiled assemblies, it's a relatively trivial thing to reverse engineer a .NET assembly.  Why don't you want the code file to be seen?

Comment: Because  if we allow they to see all files,Then they can copy the source and use it when they leave the company,I'm surprised how companies protect there small projects,You mean there is no way to prevent users to have all of source codes?

Comment: Not unless you obfuscate the code, too.  The only way to do what you're talking about is to remove the code entirely from the solution and to create it as a separate service.  That way there would be no need for the code to be on the user's machine.  I believe in most countries, there is a clause in the employment contract that would protect the company in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

There is another avenue that may be of use in your situation. Split the project up into libraries and only combine all the libraries on the build server.

The developer can build but not run on their machine. With gated check-ins the build is made available.

This works especially well if the project is web based and the build server deploys the assemblies to a web server that the developer can view.

Otherwise the notes on obfuscation and decompiling stand.